# Can't align my div to the right after in a fixed height and width

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble trying to make an image with an anchor, like a next and previous button with a round colored background, using only CSS. I want to put one image on the left, and the other on the right of the page.

The image on the left work itself just fine, but the image I want to put on the right, is displayed in a new block and also to the left of the page.

The code is something like this

```css
  main div.voltar {
  text-align: left;
  height: 52px;
  width: 52px;
  background-color: #D9C2A7;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 3px;
  box-shadow: 2px 6px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.288);
}

main div.proximo {
  height: 52px;
  width: 52px;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: #D9C2A7;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 3px;
  box-shadow: 2px 6px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.288);
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="voltar">
    <abbr title="Página dos desafios"><a href="../index.html" target="self" rel="prev"><img src="../imagens/volta.png"></a></abbr>
  </div>
  <div class="proximo">
    <abbr title="Módulo 2"><a href="../modulo-2/modulo2.html" target="_self" rel="next" class="proximo"><img src="../imagens/frente.png"></a></abbr>
  </div>
</main>
```

Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `<div>` elements are block elements and extend to 100% width by default.  You can change that, but taking a step back there's a much simpler approach.

Don't manually position what [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) can position for you.  Just set the container to `display: flex;` and justify its content with `space-between`:

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

main div.voltar {
  height: 52px;
  width: 52px;
  background-color: #D9C2A7;
  border-radius: 50%; 
  padding: 3px;
  box-shadow: 2px 6px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.288);
}
   
main div.proximo {
  height: 52px;
  width: 52px;  
  background-color: #D9C2A7; 
  border-radius: 50%; 
  padding: 3px;    
  box-shadow: 2px 6px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.288); 
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="voltar">
    <abbr title="Página dos desafios"><a href="../index.html" target="self" rel="prev"><img src="../imagens/volta.png"></a></abbr>
  </div>
  <div class="proximo">
    <abbr title="Módulo 2"><a href="../modulo-2/modulo2.html" target="_self" rel="next" class="proximo"><img src="../imagens/frente.png"></a></abbr>
  </div>
</main>
```

---

**Edit:** If you don't want to change the display for `<main>` then just wrap the target elements in a container that can be used for Flexbox:

```css
main div.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

main div.voltar {
  height: 52px;
  width: 52px;
  background-color: #D9C2A7;
  border-radius: 50%; 
  padding: 3px;
  box-shadow: 2px 6px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.288);
}
   
main div.proximo {
  height: 52px;
  width: 52px;  
  background-color: #D9C2A7; 
  border-radius: 50%; 
  padding: 3px;    
  box-shadow: 2px 6px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.288); 
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="voltar">
      <abbr title="Página dos desafios"><a href="../index.html" target="self" rel="prev"><img src="../imagens/volta.png"></a></abbr>
    </div>
    <div class="proximo">
      <abbr title="Módulo 2"><a href="../modulo-2/modulo2.html" target="_self" rel="next" class="proximo"><img src="../imagens/frente.png"></a></abbr>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Just did that in my main, but that changes all the layout of my page, the buttons went all left and below my header (I'm learning HTML and CSS by myself, must be something that i'm still not familiarized)

Comment: @PabloRicardoMarzzani: If `<main>` has other content that you don't want to change then you can wrap the relevant `<div>` elements in their own container and make that container `display: flex;`

Comment: It worked! Enveloping it in another div solved the issue!! Now I know a new thing in CSS, amazing! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. Use the flex property.

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
}

main div.voltar {
    height: 52px;
    width: 52px;
    background-color: #D9C2A7;
    border-radius: 50%; 
    padding: 3px;
    box-shadow: 2px 6px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.288);
}
   

main div.proximo {
    height: 52px;
    width: 52px;  
    background-color: #D9C2A7; 
    border-radius: 50%; 
    padding: 3px;    
    box-shadow: 2px 6px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.288); 
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="voltar">
    <abbr title="Página dos desafios"><a href="../index.html" target="self" rel="prev"><img src="../imagens/volta.png"></a></abbr>
  </div>
  <div class="proximo">
    <abbr title="Módulo 2"><a href="../modulo-2/modulo2.html" target="_self" rel="next" class="proximo"><img src="../imagens/frente.png"></a></abbr>
  </div>
</main>
```